# Namespace confilcts .NET C++

Tags: c++, sql-server-2005, c++-cli, ado

I have a project I've been working on for a while and periodically I get ambiguous symbol errors that appear to come from windows includes. They are often related to the .net namespaces. The project includes both managed and unmanaged c++ code and I have recently decided to switch from using text files for logging to using SQL server via ADO in an unmanaged class. In the header of the class I use

```
#import <C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\ado\\msado15.dll> rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )
```

as suggested by MS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675103(v=vs.85).aspx

to bring in ADO. This compiles fine in isolation but when included from the managed portion I get errors like :

```
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(216) : error C2872: 'IDataObject' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(5948) : IDataObject'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(216) : error C2872: 'IDataObject' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(5948) : IDataObject'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(246) : error C2872: 'IDropTarget' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\oleidl.h(3328) : IDropTarget'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(246) : error C2872: 'IDropTarget' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\oleidl.h(3328) : IDropTarget'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IDropTarget'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(771) : error C2872: 'IMessageFilter' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(6328) : IMessageFilter'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(771) : error C2872: 'IMessageFilter' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\objidl.h(6328) : IMessageFilter'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::IMessageFilter'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(1041) : error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
3>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\comdefsp.h(1041) : error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
3>        could be 'c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
3>        or       'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
```

Is there some way to encapsulate conflicting namespaces so that it doesn't affect .NET ? The problem keeps cropping up and there seems to be something here I don't fully understand.
Many thanks,
Bruce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove some of your using namespace declarations and use there full name to avoid the conflict.